# Use of RTP Marker Bit

Tags: audio, voip, packet

RFC 3551 indicates that it should be set only on the first packet for a talkspurt and that it must not be set if silence suppression isn't in use.

I am not clear though on whether or not there exists any scenario where it would be proper to have the Marker Bit enabled on every packet.

Is there any situation where it would be RFC-compliant to set the RTP Marker Bit on every packet in a call?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any scenario when the market bit should be enabled for all packets. On the receiver side this is used for jitter buffer handling, so the receiver might begin buffering a few frames when it sees a market bit (because at the marker bit you are more safe to prebuffer without adding gliches to the voice).

I guess that sipstack implementation can't even handle such thing correctly (receiving the market bit with each packet).